# Excel: How can I give different people various levels of protection and access

Tags: vba, excel, passwords, password-protection

I have an excel spreadsheet that 3 different types of people can access, I want these 3 types of people to have different access rights. I want there to be people with full access, so can change the workbook, change the cells, change the contents and formats of the cells, etc. there are people with some access, so can only change some cells and can go on any of the sheets that are visible when the spreadsheet is access, and I want there to be people with limited access so can only go on certain sheets, change cells that are necessary to retrieve the data that is associated to that value, and cannot save the file.

Is there a way of doing this?

What I would really like is for when the file opens to ask the user for a password, and, dependent on what the password is, different cells are locked and different levels of access is applied.

Comment: In the workbook_open event, you can have an inputbox for password but might be more effective to do an if statement for application.user?

Comment: I mean, this is possible, but it would be pretty easy for a user to simply disable macros, and then turn all sheets to xlSheetVisible from a different workbook, or copy the contents into a different workbook.  The point is, Excel is not, and was never designed to be, a secure program

Comment: There is no simple way. You are looking at a pretty big chunk of code. This is far too large for a simple question. The first things you need to learn are: 1) How to ask for passwords (using inputboxes, for example), 2) How to protect/unprotect single cells and ranges using VBA. 3) How to create your custom protection macros (it involves, for my own, writing in a hidden sheet the specs of protection. Ex The protection level currently being used (1, 2, 3 for example). This might be referred to in your code/events, for example, and the Wb_Change refers to it to verify the user CAN modify.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, there's not a very secure way to do this.  You could, on workbook open, prompt for a password, then have some statement that says "If password is X, set these cells as protected.  If password is Y, set other cells as protected. If password is Z, set other cells as protected.  If not 'X, Y, or Z, close workbook".  The issue with that is that it's not very secure.  Anyone with even a little VB knowledge could likely get by this...so doing something like this might lull you into a false sense of security.

Comment: Perhaps you could make three workbooks, and give each person their respective workbook and have them on some drive that all can access.  Then you can create a file that combines all their info?

Comment: @BruceWayne your first comment is basically what I want, it doesn't have to be overly secure so I think that'd be fine

Comment: This is why you use username as I pointed out. Eliminates the password insecurity. Much harder to login as someone else.

Comment: @findwindow Ideally both would be used, can you please show me how I could have a message box that appears and asks for user name and password?

Comment: I agree with @findwindow - using the windows User name would definitely be more secure than just a VB prompt.

Comment: @BenSmith you don't prompt for username. Just test for it. if application.username ="Smith, Ben" then...

Comment: But the problem with that is there's going to be a lot of people accessing this file, so what I want to have three different usernames, e.g. "full", "partial", "view", and a password for each of these usernames

Comment: So do a case statement for the three cases and an else. You're just mentioning the else now... Also, I am not holding your hand because 1) I have my own work to do and 2) at SO you should make an effort before asking for help please.

Answer (score 1):

**First assign named ranges to the areas you want to protect**, using a suffix indicating what to do with them. You can do that by  selecting the range and typing a name that is not a valid Cell address left of the formula bar.

[image]

I created ranges named Someting_4U, which You and I can edit and Something_4Me, which only I can edit

**Now copy the below code** in the main **ThisWorkbook** module

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, Nm As Name
```

' Unprotect your workbook and sheets

```
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "onlyVbaPassWord"
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sht.Unprotect "onlyVbaPassWord"
    Next Sht
```

' Unprotect the appropriate named ranges and protect the others

```
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names

        ' The next `Select Case` statement implements your business logic
        Select Case Application.UserName
            Case "Me", "Myself", "I"
                Nm.RefersToRange.Locked = False
            Case "You", "Yourself", "Thou"
                If Nm.Name Like "*_4U" Then
                    Nm.RefersToRange.Locked = False
                Else
                    Nm.RefersToRange.Locked = True
                End If
            Case Else
                Nm.RefersToRange.Locked = True
        End Select
    Next Nm
```

' Protect your sheets and workbook again

```
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sht.Protect "onlyVbaPassWord"
    Next Sht
    ThisWorkbook.Protect "onlyVbaPassWord"
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can add more complex rules, like I can only type text, you can also insert lines and change formatting, but then it becomes too dependent on your situation for me to guess

Comment: Ok, I've got the code in a module, am I meant to be running the code before I shut the file? When I open the file I don't get asked for a password?

Comment: @Ben without meaning to be rude.  If you read the code that Dirk wrote and expected to be prompted for a password, then to be frank this task is probably beyond you at the moment.  The above code gives you the clever bit that you will need to incorporate into other code.  The comments from others are all good advise.

Comment: @BenSmith, This code does not belong in *a* module it belongs in *the* main *ThisWorkbook* module. See edit